# Spring integration - sftp/ftp

Tags: sftp, spring-integration

I am using spring integration file/sftp module, how can I avoid downloading partial file? I don't have control on external process pushing the files into ftp/sftp.

Answer (score 3):

You need to gain control (or influence) over the sender. A number of techniques can be used - rename the file after successful transfer (that's what Spring Integration does) or send a second file `foo.complete` and only fetch the file when it's complete.

There's nothing you can do if they won't cooperate.